# AR drone 2 Timeout cmd_vel

Tags: ros, navigation, ardrone-autonomy, timeout, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !

I have a question about the AR drone 2.
Is it possible to reset the cmd_vel every X ms from the package ardrone_autonomy ?

I know it's possible on the Bebop, just modifying timeout_cmd_vel = MY_VALUE in the yaml file (bebop_autonomy/bebop_driver/config/default.yaml).

Thanks for your help !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254687/ar-drone-2-timeout-cmd_vel/) by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this wiki](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/wiki/AR-Drone-Parameters), there isn't a parameter that does that.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0